# Getting Postgresql Running In Mac: Database "postgres" does not exist

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I followed these instructions to get postgresql running on mac. Note that I am using Homebrew to install, and the current version installable through brew is 9.2.1, so I changed the version numbers in the instructions here: http://rails3hub.blogspot.com/2012/02/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x.html

Everything went swimmingly, but I can't get into psql to create dbs and whatnot. if I try `psql` i get `psql: FATAL:  database "myusername" does not exist`

if i try `psql -U root` i get `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`

if i try to follow the instruction in the blog to use pgAdmin as my postgres console, eg `psql -d postgres < /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.1/share/postgresql/extension/adminpack--1.0.sql` i get the same role "postgres" does not exist error.

I have no clue how to get this up and running, I simply want to get into psql just as I would mysql -U root, create a db, and get started with a site.

Anybody have any advice? I can post more information, and I'm on Mac OSX fyi.

Comment: First, we have no idea what instructions you followed. Second, it seems either they were non-complete or there were some errors following them.

Comment: i forgot to paste the link in. here are the instructions i followed http://rails3hub.blogspot.com/2012/02/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x.html i edited my question as well

Comment: The first problem you see is mentioned in the comments in the same link. You have to `createdb mysername`.

Comment: Try `psql -d template1` and see what you get.

Comment: yup, that's it. i don't see that comment in the links, but in any case thanks. want to add a short answer below so i can mark it as correct?

Comment: I flagged the question for migration to serverfault.SE, where it would be better suited.