# psql: FATAL: database "<user>" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgres.app

I'm using [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) for Mac. I've used it in the past on other machines but it's giving me some trouble when installing on my MacBook. I've installed the application and I ran:

```
psql -h localhost
```

It returns:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "<user>" does not exist
```

It seems I can't even run the console to create the database that it's attempting to find. The same thing happens when I just run:

```
psql
```

or if I launch psql from the application drop down menu:

Machine stats:

- OSX 10.8.4
- psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.4

Any help is appreciated.

I've also attempted to install PostgreSQL via Homebrew and I'm getting the same issue. I've also read the application's [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627095157/http://postgresapp.com/documentation) that states:

> When Postgres.app first starts up, it creates the $USER database,
> which is the default database for `psql` when none is specified. The
> default user is $USER, with no password.

So it would seem the application is not creating $USER.  However, I've installed->uninstalled-reinstalled several times now so it must be something with my machine.

I found the answer but I'm not sure exactly how it works as the user who answered on this thread -> [Getting Postgresql Running In Mac: Database "postgres" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515834/getting-postgresql-running-in-mac-database-postgres-does-not-exist) didn't follow up. I used the following command to get psql to open:

```
psql -d template1
```

Comment: What does `psql -d postgres -U postgres -h localhost` show?
Without flags it defaults to the CLI user, and I would have said it defaults to the "postgres" admin db but I don't have a mac to test on.

Comment: @bma That gives me psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist, which originally brought me here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301826/psql-fatal-role-postgres-does-not-exist. I've attempted to use that answer but I'm getting the same result -> psql: FATAL: database "user" does not exist

Comment: Have you looked in the db log? I wonder if more detail would be emitted there.

Comment: I had the same problem. Just doing `createdb <user>` worked for me.

Comment: run the command as `psql -U user -d postgres`, this ensures that , user is connected to postgres database, which is already present. So we need to pass database also while login.

Answer (score 1501, accepted):

It appears that your package manager failed to create the database named $user for you.  The reason that

```
psql -d template1
```

works for you is that template1 is a database created by postgres itself, and is present on all installations.
You are apparently able to log in to template1, so you must have some rights assigned to you by the database.  Try this at a shell prompt:

```
createdb
```

and then see if you can log in again with

```
psql -h localhost
```

This will simply create a database for your login user, which I think is what you are looking for.  If createdb fails, then you don't have enough rights to make your own database, and you will have to figure out how to fix the homebrew package.

Comment: In my case i wrote `$ createdb -h localhost` to solve the error `could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server`. After that i may connect to postgresql console via `psql -h localhost`.

Comment: I still get a password prompt'd and have no idea which one is it, which one is the default postgres app password?

Comment: Thanks @Kirk. Do we really need `-d template1` in your first command? I've seen "template1" in tutorials all over the Internet but it only serves to confuse me. A more logical approach would be, in my opinion 1) Create the PostgreSQL user e.g. "usera" 2) Create a database with the same name as the user "usera" (I think this is crazy but it seems PostgreSQL requires it) 3) Log into PostgreSQL as the super user "postgres" and assign the privileges of database "usera" to the user "usera" (oh my god, is this really the real life?)

Comment: @eric :  The -d template1 is only there to check that the OP could log in at all.  Since it is created at initdb time, it always exists, and was an easy check.  From that point forward, your procedure is generally "real life".

Comment: @ExiRe You just cured a massive headache I was having with one simple command. Thanks!

Comment: To be a little more explicit you can run the command:  `createdb \`whoami\`` which will create a DB based on your current user name

Comment: It doesn't seem a good idea to create a whole new database just to let the user get in. `psql -d postgres` as per some of the other answers seem much more deserving of some upvotes.

Comment: `createdb -h localhost -U <user> <user>` is what worked for me

Answer (score 334):

From the terminal, just Run the command on your command prompt window. **(Not inside psql)**.

```
createdb <user>
```

And then try to run postgres again.

Comment: And i was trying in psql template. damn

Comment: also you can just run ```createdb```

Comment: tip for users like me ;) (Not inside psql). means when you just open terminal window just enter this createdb as first command and then try to login in psql.

Comment: Great! Worked for me on OSX.

Comment: `createdb: error: database creation failed: ERROR:  permission denied to create database`

Comment: `createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`

Answer (score 257):

By default, postgres tries to connect to a database with the same name as your user.  To prevent this default behaviour, just specify user and database:

```
psql -U Username DatabaseName
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know the reason for such design - why in the world would I want to go my-name database by default?

Comment: @eric Databases are often used by services running as a dedicated user. So I guess the strategy of using the user name as the default database name is probably more useful than using some fixed default database name (e.g. "postgres").

Comment: how do you run SQL script that actually creates database? in my case it always tries to connect to the database <user> when my goal is to create another DB: `psql -U Username -f create_db.sql` this will return error: `database Username doesn't exists`

Comment: Fantastic answer thanks, but begs the question why is it not in the command line help? psql --help

Comment: `psql -U Username postgres` when you have no databases yet

Comment: This is terrible design considering you can log in first, as the postgres user, without specifying a database (obviously, since one may not exist.) Also users exist outside the scope of a single database. This behavior isn't intuitive at all.

Answer (score 84):

1. Login as default user: `sudo -i -u postgres`
2. Create new User: `createuser --interactive`
3. When prompted for role name, enter linux username, and select Yes to superuser question.
4. Still logged in as postgres user, create a database: `createdb <username_from_step_3>`
5. Confirm error(s) are gone by entering: `psql` at the command prompt.
6. Output should show `psql (x.x.x) Type "help" for help.`

Comment: I needed to do this in Windows. Set the new pg username to the Linux un. Fixed.

Comment: If you don't want the user to be a superuser, at (4) run this command in a Linux account with `sudo` permission instead: `sudo -u <username> createdb <dbname>`

Answer (score 59):

Login using default template1 database:

```
#psql -d template1
#template1=# \l

  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |  Access privileges  
-----------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------
 postgres  | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/gogasca         +
           |         |          |             |             | gogasca=CTc/gogasca
 template1 | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/gogasca         +
           |         |          |             |             | gogasca=CTc/gogasca
(3 rows)
```

Create a database with your userId:

```
template1=# CREATE DATABASE gogasca WITH OWNER gogasca ENCODING 'UTF8';
CREATE DATABASE
```

Quit and then login again

```
template1=# \q
gonzo:~ gogasca$ psql -h localhost
psql (9.4.0)
Type "help" for help.

gogasca=# \l
                                List of databases
   Name    |  Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |  Access privileges  
-----------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+---------------------
 gogasca   | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/gogasca         +
           |         |          |             |             | gogasca=CTc/gogasca
 template1 | gogasca | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/gogasca         +
           |         |          |             |             | gogasca=CTc/gogasca
(4 rows)
```

Answer (score 27):

I faced the same error when I trying to open postgresql on mac

```
psql: FATAL:  database "user" does not exist
```

I found this simple command to solve it:

method1

```
$ createdb --owner=postgres --encoding=utf8 user
```

and type

```
 psql
```

Method 2:

```
psql -d postgres
```

Answer (score 27):

Post installation of postgres, in my case version is 12.2, I did run the below command `createdb`.

```
$ createdb `whoami`

$ psql

psql (12.2)
Type "help" for help.

macuser=#
```

Answer (score 24):

**Step 1:**

`psql -d template1`

now you should be on psql terminal

**Step 2:**

`CREATE DATABASE username;`

*make sure you use semicolon (;) after the database name*;

optional: on psql terminal type `\ls` or `\l` to list all the databases;

**Step 3:**

`psql -h localhost`

now you should be connected;

Answer (score 18):

Try using-

`psql -d postgres`

I was also facing the same issue when I ran `psql`

Comment: psql -d worked instead of psql -h (which is not working)

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem, a simple `psql -d postgres` did it (Type the command in the terminal)

Answer (score 8):

This error can also occur if the environment variable PGDATABASE is set to the name of a database that does not exist.

On OSX, I saw the following error while trying to launch psql from the Postgress.app menu:

`psql: FATAL:  database "otherdb" does not exist`

The solution to the error was to remove `export PGDATABASE=otherdb` from `~/.bash_profile`:

Further, if PGUSER is set to something other than your username, the following error will occur:

`psql: FATAL:  role "note" does not exist`

The solution is to remove `export PGUSER=notme` from `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if it is already added in the answers, Anatolii Stepaniuk answer was very helpful which is the following.

```
psql -U Username postgres # when you have no databases yet
```

Answer (score 5):

As the [createdb documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-createdb.html) states:

> The first database is always created by the initdb command when the data storage area is initialized... This database is called postgres.

So if certain OS/postgresql distributions do that differently, it is certainly not the default/standard (just verified that `initdb` on openSUSE 13.1 creates the DB "postgres", but not "<user>"). Long story short, `psql -d postgres` is expected to be used when using a user other than "postgres".

Obviously the accepted answer, running `createdb` to create a DB named like the user, works as well, but creates a superfluous DB.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question is the first in search results, I'll put a different solution for a different problem here anyway, in order not to have a duplicate title.

The same error message can come up when running a query file in `psql` without specifying a database. Since there is no `use` statement in postgresql, we have to specify the database on the command line, for example:

```
psql -d db_name -f query_file.sql
```

Comment: and db template1 always exists

Answer (score 3):

First off, it's helpful to create a database named the same as your current use, to prevent the error when you just want to use the default database and create new tables without declaring the name of a db explicitly.

Replace "skynotify" with your username:

```
psql -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE skynotify ENCODING 'UTF-8';"
```

-d explicitly declares which database to use as the default for SQL statements that don't explicitly include a db name during this interactive session.

BASICS FOR GETTING A CLEAR PICTURE OF WHAT YOUR PostgresQL SERVER has in it.

You must connect to an existing database to use psql interactively.  Fortunately, you can ask psql for a list of databases:

```
psql -l
```

.

```
                                          List of databases
               Name               | Owner  | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    | Access privileges 
----------------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------
 skynotify                        | skynotify | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 myapp_dev                        | skynotify | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres                         | skynotify | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 ruby-getting-started_development | skynotify | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0                        | skynotify | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/skynotify          +
                                  |           |          |             |             | skynotify=CTc/skynotify
 template1                        | skynotify | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/skynotify          +
                                  |           |          |             |             | skynotify=CTc/skynotify
(6 rows)
```

This does NOT start the interactive console, it just outputs a text based table to the terminal.

As another answers says, postgres is always created, so you should use it as your failsafe database when you just want to get the console started to work on other databases.  If it isn't there, then list the databases and then use any one of them.

In a similar fashion, select tables from a database:

```
psql -d postgres -c "\dt;"
```

My "postgres" database has no tables, but any database that does will output a text based table to the terminal (standard out).

And for completeness, we can select all rows from a table too:

```
psql -d ruby-getting-started_development -c "SELECT * FROM widgets;"
```

.

```
 id | name | description | stock | created_at | updated_at 
----+------+-------------+-------+------------+------------
(0 rows)
```

Even if there are zero rows returned, you'll get the field names.

If your tables have more than a dozen rows, or you're not sure, it'll be more useful to start with a count of rows to understand how much data is in your database:

```
 psql -d ruby-getting-started_development -c "SELECT count(*) FROM widgets;"
```

.

```
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

And don't that that "1 row" confuse you, it just represents how many rows are returned by the query, but the 1 row contains the count you want, which is 0 in this example.

NOTE: a db created without an owner defined will be owned by the current user.

Answer (score 2):

had the problem with using the JDBC driver, so one just has to add the database (maybe redundantly depending on the tool you may use) after the host name in the URL, e.g.
**`jdbc:postgres://<host(:port)>/<db-name>`**

further details are documented here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/jdbc-use.html#JDBC-CONNECT

Comment: I know it's a little off topic considering it was only asked for psql, but Google brought me here with my problem so I think its worth mentioning here

Answer (score 1):

You can just run this command

```
createdb `whoami`
```

and then you can run `psql` command

Answer (score 1):

tldr;

```bash
psql postgres
```

I found the simple and direct answer I was looking for. This works on macOS with PostgreSQL installed using the command `brew install postgresql`

---

### long version

`psql` is the client that accesses the default `postgresql` database created by the installation script provided by the Homebrew package (`brew`). So, running the command `psql` means running the client program and connecting to the database named as the second argument, which is `postgresql`.

Regarding the issue mentioned in the subject, [the tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-createdb.html) (which I encourage you to read before posting on StackOverflow) precisely describes and provides the solution. Let's quote:

```
createdb: error: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "joe" does not exist
```

> where your own login name is mentioned. This will happen if the
> administrator has not created a PostgreSQL user account for you.
> (PostgreSQL user accounts are distinct from operating system user
> accounts.) If you are the administrator, see Chapter 22 for help
> creating accounts. You will need to become the operating system user
> under which PostgreSQL was installed (usually postgres) to create the
> first user account.

Quoting the tutorial once again, here is the solution to solve the problem.

> To create a new database, in this example named joe, you use the following command:

`$ createdb joe`

And voilà, you can log into your scintillant psql and explore the database.

```
$ psql
psql (14.10 (Homebrew))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to postgres via existing superuser.

Create a Database by the name of user you are connecting through to postgres.

```
create database username;
```

Now try to connect via username

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when solving this problem

i ran sudo -i -u postgress --> to gain access to my postgres database.

Then enter your password.

it would allow you to now enter psql
which would prompt you for other command

Cheers!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31802437)

Answer (score -1):

Had this problem when installing postgresql via homebrew.

Had to create the default "postgres" super user with:

> createuser --interactive postgres answer y to for super user
>
> createuser --interactive user answer y to for super user

Answer (score -1):

you can set the database name you want to connect to in env variable PGDATABASE=database_name. If you dont set this psql default database name is as username. after setting this you don't have to createdb

Comment: I found I still had to create the database via createdb.  I think Nav means something like "if you set the env var to a db that already exists..."

Comment: oh yeah you have to create database

Answer (score -1):

Was running postgres in docker. In cli I  was getting the error "root" role doesn't exist.

> su - postgres

> psql

solved the problem.

PostgreSQL has its own user on the system which is created when PostgreSQL is installed. The postgres user is able to log into PostgreSQL without using a password. No other user is able to log into PostgreSQL.

This means that before using PostgreSQL, you will need to switch to that user account with the command:

su - postgres
You will then be able to log into the PosgreSQL client with the command:

psql
You will not be able to access the database from the command line as any other user.

Answer (score -3):

I still had the issue above after installing postgresql using homebrew - I resolved it by putting /usr/local/bin in my path before /usr/bin

Answer (score -22):

This is a basic misunderstanding. Simply typing:

> pgres

will result in this response:

```
pgres <db_name>
```

It will succeed without error if the user has the permissions to access the db.

One can go into the details of the exported environment variables but that's unnecessary .. this is too basic to fail for any other reason.

Comment: Also it did not recommend how to resolve the issue, so did not answer the question.

Comment: never heard of `pgres`