# Postgres user does not exist?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I have just installed Postgres and have been tinkering with it and various configurations for 1-2 hours.

I am stuck on **being unable to change to the postgres-user**

`$ su - postgres` yields the following error: `su: unknown login: postgres`

`$ sudo -u postgres psql` yields the following error: `sudo: unknown user: postgres`

These attempts are made as the normal user. Trying them as root has the exact same results. I have installed postgres via Homebrew on OS X, and I have read the instructions multple times.

Comment: Are you just trying to run psql?

Comment: Well yes, I want to run as the proper `postgres` user.

Comment: On some Mac OS X flavours, with some installation methods, I think the user is created as `postgres_` instead. Note trailing underscore. Also, are you sure you (or the installer)actually created the PostgreSQL instance and started the database?

Comment: I was too unable to switch to `postgres` user. Solved the problem after installing `postgresql-server` package.

Comment: @krystah I believe you should rather mark kangkyu's answer at the correct answer. That's the most appropriate solution to the above query.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

`psql`: Logs me in with my default username

`psql -U postgres`: Logs me in as the postgres user

Sudo doesn't seem to be required for me.

I use Postgres.app for my OS X postgres database. It removed the headache of making sure the installation was working and the database server was launched properly. Check it out here: http://postgresapp.com

Edit: Credit to @Erwin Brandstetter for correcting my use of the arguments.

Comment: I installed using Brew and it didn't create a user called postgres or _postgres (as far as I can see) so this failed for me.  @kangkyu solution explains and walks you through the issues - assuming you don't have postgres user then: `psql postgres` and `psql -d postgres`.

Answer (score 48):

By `psql --help`, when you didn't set options for database name (without `-d` option) it would be your username, if you didn't do `-U`, the database username would be your username too, etc.

But by `initdb` (to create the first database) command it doesn't have your username as any database name. It has a database named `postgres`. [The first database is always created by the initdb command when the data storage area is initialized. This database is called postgres.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/manage-ag-createdb.html)

So if you don't have another database named your username, you need to do `psql -d postgres` for psql command to work. And it seems it gives `-d` option by default, `psql postgres` also works.

If you have created another database names the same to your username, (it should be done with `createdb`) then you may command `psql` only. And it seems the first database user name sets as your machine username by brew.

```
psql -d <first database name> -U <first database user name>
```

or,

```
psql -d postgres -U <your machine username>
psql -d postgres
```

would work by default.

Comment: Still works. I installed postgres 13 with `homebrew` and this one has worked for me.

Answer (score 19):

OS X tends to prefix the system account names with "_"; you don't say what version of OS X you're using, but at least in 10.8 and 10.9 the _postgres user exists in a default install. Note that you won't be able to `su` to this account (except as root), since it doesn't have a password. `sudo -u _postgres`, on the other hand, should work fine.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for.
Is there anything I can do to rename the user to just "postgres"? Logging in as that _postgres user leads to psql complaining that the "_postgres" user doesn't exist. I'm trying to restore a clean postgres instance with a backup file from another database

Comment: @ChrisReyes Changing the name of system accounts may break system components that use them, so I'd strongly recommend against it. You could create another user account with the name "postgres" and use that, but if I understand right (which I might not), what you're running into is that the user account *within the postgres database* is not named _postgres. AIUI the account names within the DB are separate from the system account names, so there shouldn't be a problem running a DB instance under the "_postgres" system account, and opening that DB with the "postgres" database account.

Answer (score 9):

For me This was the solution on macOS
ReInstall the psql

```
brew install postgres
```

Start PostgreSQL server

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

Initialize DB

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

If this command throws an error the rm the old database file and re-run the above command

```
rm -r /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Create a new database

```
createdb postgres_test
psql -W postegres_test
```

You will be logged into this db and can create a user in here to login

Comment: Great Answer! Helped me. There's a small typo in create-a-new-database: `createdb postgres_test`and then `psql -W postgres_test`. You have an extra "e" in postegres_test.

Comment: @Fredster Glad, it helped you!

Answer (score 5):

```
psql -U postgres
```

Worked fine for me in case of db name: postgres & username: postgres. So you do not need to write sudo.

And in the case other db, you may try

```
psql -U yourdb postgres
```

As it is given in Postgres help:

```
psql [OPTION]... [DBNAME [USERNAME]]
```

Comment: My case: `$ psql -U postgres` generates output `psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist`, but `psql postgres` works.

Comment: I got error `psql: error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Answer (score 4):

I get exactly the same errors as kryshah with `su - postgres` and `sudo -u postgres psql`. 
DanielM's answer gives also errors.

### Outputs when wrong settings

Answer however from przbabu's comment.

```
masi$ psql
psql: FATAL:  database "masi" does not exist
masi$ psql -U postgres
psql: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
masi$ psql postgres
psql (9.4.1)
Type "help" for help.
```

I think the some part of this problem may be in owner settings in OSX

```
masi$ ls -al /Users/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   7 root      admin  238 Jul  3 09:50 .
drwxr-xr-x  37 root      wheel 1326 Jul  2 19:02 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root      wheel    0 Sep 10  2014 .localized
drwxrwxrwt   7 root      wheel  238 Apr  9 19:49 Shared
drwxr-xr-x   2 root      admin   68 Jul  3 09:50 postgres
drwxr-xr-x+ 71 masi      staff 2414 Jul  3 09:50 masi
```

but doing `sudo chown -R postgres:staff /Users/postgres` gives `chown: invalid user: ‘postgres:staff’`.

In short, this is not the solution the problem. 
Use the tools provided by the postgres installation to create a user and database.

### To get right settings and outputs

There are specific commands after postgres installation to add a new user to the database system.
After initdb, run the following as described [here](http://www.tunnelsup.com/setting-up-postgres-on-mac-osx)

```
createuser --pwprompt postgres
createdb -Opostgres -Eutf8 masi_development
psql -U postgres -W masi_development
```

To avoid the password request all the time, you have three choices as described [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/14741/69807).

Answer (score 3):

the discussion and answer here was massively helpful to me:

[psql: FATAL: database "<user>" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist)

Comment: And this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist/46951367#46951367

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to create a new role, you can name  :

```
sudo adduser <new_user_role>
```

Answer (score 0):

This video helped me.
While using "initdb" you need to use --username="username", here you can use any username. When you initialize another db instance with this utility then there is no default user for that which you need to tell postgres.

You can use this:
initdb -D "location of data directory" --username=youruser -W

To have a clear understanding of this you can watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdijTz8n5ok

Answer (score 0):

Install postgres-server:

```
yum install postgresql-server -y
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution is simple:
log in as root 
and after:

```
su - postgres

psql
```