# Can't access Postgres superuser in fresh PG installation

Tags: postgresql

I followed the installation guide [here](http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/) to install Postgres on my Mac OS 10.10 using Homebrew.

When I run `su - postgres`, it prompts for a password. Entering my root password fails with the message `su: Sorry`.

I've checked other answers where `sudo su - postgres` worked for people, but it doesn't work for me. Entering my root password here returns `su: unknown login: postgres`.

What else could the password be if not my root password? This is a brand new installation and never asked me to set a password.

And yes, I've started Postgres as instructed in the above guide using  `lunchy start postgres`.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Try _postgres user instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Postgres user does not exist?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122598/postgres-user-does-not-exist)

Comment: You should always just use `sudo -u postgres -i` . No need for `su`. But in this case with homebrew it sounds like the user is named `_postgres`.

Comment: _postgres didn't work but psql postgres from that link did work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to login as `postgres` into the postgres engine. But if your Mac doesn't have a user `postgres`, then you won't be able to login no matter what password you use. Alternatively, use any super user to login.

With my current user as a super user, I simply logged into postgres by using `pgsql`