# Where should I `initdb` on a first postgres install?

Tags: database, postgresql, development-environment

Setting up a development environment on a new machine, brew installed postgres. Now I need to `initdb` for the first time, which directory should i specify for this command?

Comment: Anything you choose. That's why it is a parameter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems brew failed to create a database when installing postgres, the solution for me, as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist), was to run `createdb` then all was fine.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're on OS X, given "brew", then:

- If you intend to run the postgres server under your own user account, put it somewhere like `/Users/MyUserName/Library/postgres_data`.
- If you intend to run it from `launchd` as a system service, as a dedicated postgres user, put it somewhere in `/Library/`.

However, Homebrew takes this out of your hands a bit with [`brew services`](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew):

```
brew tap homebrew/services
```

which I recommend using. I don't have a Mac and the docs appear to be nonexistent for this, but it looks like it's as simple as:

```
brew services start postgres
```

If not, the interactive help will probably tell you what you need to do.