# FATAL: database <name> does not exist

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dbeaver

I am trying to create my own `Spring Boot` application with a `POSTGRESQL` database. I have started using `docker` to mount the database, with a `docker-compose` whose values ​​are as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
    products-postgresql:
      image: postgres:9.6
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 5450:5432
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: superadmin
        POSTGRES_DB: products
      volumes:
        - D:\microservicios\workspace\SpringSecurity\volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

With the `docker-compose up -d` command, I managed to get it up easily, [image]
[image]

The problem occurs to me when trying to connect with `DBeaver` to the database. I have configured it as a new `POSTGRESQL` connection, passing the connection data similar to those of docker-compose, (`database` = products, `host` = localhost, `user` = postgres, `password` = superadmin....) but it returns `FATAL error: database "products" does not exist`.

[image: Imagen de conexion con DBeaver]

I've seen similar posts, like this [psql: FATAL: database "" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633422/psql-fatal-database-user-does-not-exist) , but they don't work for me.
I have verified that I don't have any other application using the same port.

Could you tell me what I may be doing wrong, or what I have left to configure? Thanks

***UPDATE***: Image showing that the container lifts my database

[image: From Docker]

Comment: Just curious: why you are using such an outdated Postgres version?

Comment: I took advantage of the version of postgresql that we had at work. Could it be a version problem? @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: With docker-compose, the database should be created (empty), and then you can fill it @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: @AdolinK.Yes, of course, sorry.

Comment: Can you connect from inside the container?

Comment: I can, I just updated the post with the image from docker desktop
@ÁlvaroGonzález

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still don't understand why, I had to change the port of my container to 5432 (the one used by POSTGRESQL), and it finally worked for me.

```
version: "3"
services:
    products-postgresql:
      image: postgres:9.6
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 5432:5432
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: superadmin
        POSTGRES_DB: products
      volumes:
        - D:\microservicios\workspace\SpringSecurity\volumes:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
```

Comment: That means you had another (vestigial) instance of PostgreSQL running on port 5450, which was overcasting the one you intended. And hence, by changing the port number, it worked for you as you were able to connect to the intended instance.