# What should the flow be for 'psql' command? Windows command line

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

I can access psql with 'psql -U postgres' followed by the password, but I can't access my defined user with the same 'psql -U definedUser' it just says 'definedUser isn't a database'.

Just to clarify.

How do I log in as a predefined user?
How do I quickly access psql from the command line?

Comment: use -d or --dbname to tell psql what database to use. The default is using the username also for the database name. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: Thanks Frank. Would it be
```
psql -U desiredUsername -d desiredDatabase
```
?

Comment: Yes, but I would avoid upper case in names and stick to just lower case.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I've figured it out. This comment is what swung it.. Very succinct and easy to solve. If the user has been created successfully, by default when you log in with said user psql attempts to find a database of the same name if it doesn't you get an error like 'desiredUsername isn't a database'.

You need to add the database name after the chosen username

```
psql -U desiredUsername desiredDatabase
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21827460/15592981